# Replace img scr on click and not require page refresh. Ajax Jquery Javascript Php MySql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following 2 php scripts.  booking.php is created on the fly doing a call to a mysql database and returning results into the tables.  To make this a somewhat simple example and only am showing a few fields...actually table has 54 fields in them.

The idea behind this is every table is a Customer order. The openbutton or closebutton is a image representing what status the order is in. If it is closed the closedbutton image appears.  If the order is opened then the openbutton image appears. when I click on the

Everything work (process wise), however, the image only allows me to click it once per table and requires me to refresh the page to click on it again.

What is want is to be able to click the openbutton/closedbutton image on a table as many times as I want and have the correct image appear after I click it and the mysql table has processed it.

booking.php

```
<?php
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.status_button').click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var I = element.attr('id');
var id=$('#id'+I).val();
var sname = $(this).attr('title');

$.post('openclose.php', {id: id, sname: sname},
function(data){
var response = (data).split(';',2);
$('#messageA'+I).html(response[0]);
$('#messageA'+I).hide();
$('#messageA'+I).fadeIn(1500);
$('#messageB'+I).html(response[1]);
$('#messageB'+I).hide();
$('#messageB'+I).fadeIn(1500);
});
return false
;})
;});
</script>
<style type='text/css'>
table {border: 1px solid black}
td, tr {border: 0}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Actions</th>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' id='id1' size='3' readonly='readonly' value='1'></td>
<td><input type='text' id='year1' size='2' value='2013'></td>
<td><input type='text' id='fname1' size='10' value='Brian'></td>
<td><input type='text' id='lname1' size='15'value='Smith'></td>
<td><div id='messageB1'><a id='1', href='#' class = 'status_button' title='Close1'>           </div>
<div id='messageA1'><img src='images/openbutton.jpg', title='Order Status' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img></div></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Actions</th>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' id='id2' size='3' readonly='readonly' value='2'></td>
<td><input type='text' id='year2' size='2' value='2014'></td>
<td><input type='text' id='fname2' size='10' value='Kurt'></td>
<td><input type='text' id='lname2' size='15'value='Jones'></td>
<td><div id='messageB2'><a id='2', href='#' class = 'status_button' title='Open2'>    </div>
<div id='messageA2'><img src='images/closebutton.jpg', title='Order Status' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img></div></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Actions</th>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' id='id3' size='3' readonly='readonly' value='2'></td>
<td><input type='text' id='year3' size='2' value='2014'></td>
<td><input type='text' id='fname3' size='10' value='Ryan'></td>
<td><input type='text' id='lname3' size='15'value='Davis'></td>
<td><div id='messageB3'><a id='3', href='#' class = 'status_button' title='Open3'></div>
<div id='messageA3'><img src='images/openbutton.jpg', title='Order Status' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img></div></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body> 
?>
```

openclose.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$id=$_POST['id'];
$sname=$_POST['sname'];

$rest = substr($sname, 0, -1);

if ($rest == "Open")
    $change="O";
else
    $change="C";    

$query = "UPDATE info SET status_ = '$change' WHERE id = $id";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die ( mysql_error ());

if ($change == "O")
    $image ="<img src='images/openbutton.jpg', title='Order Status' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img>";
else
    $image="<img src='images/closebutton.jpg', title='Order Status' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img>"; 

if ($rest == "Close")
    $status_change ="<a id='$id', href='#' class = 'status_button' title='Open'>";
else
    $status_change= "<a id='$id', href='#' class = 'status_button' title='Close'>"; 

echo "$image;$status_change";

?>
```

Comment: at first: remove php tags in booking.php next i'm looking & thinking for the problem :)

Comment: lol yeah that would probably help :)

Comment: The php tags are in there because what I posted is the "result" of php creating the html on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.status_button').click(function(){
```

should be:

```
$(document).on('click', '.status_button', function(){
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

And...

```
echo "$image;$status_change";
```

go to:

```
echo $image.";".$status_change.";";
```

Comment: Thanks Carter....made the change. Does not solve the problem, but appreciated anyway.

Comment: Put your js in jsLint... I have no idea what is going on... Other than not using the correct event handler for your version of jQuery.

Comment: Made your additional change. Again - I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

make openbutton & closebutton changes in the first page
like this

```
<div id='message'><img src='images/closebutton.jpg' id='message' title='Order Status' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img></div>
<script>
    $('img#message').click(function(){
        var messageimage;
        messageimage = $('img#message').attr();
        if(messageimage == 'images/closebutton.jpg'){
            $('img#message').attr('src','images/openbutton.jpg');
        }else{
           $('img#message').attr('src','images/closebutton.jpg'); 
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Pooya - made your changes and the exact same issue is happening....it only allows the button to be clicked once.

Comment: can you give a url to your project for testing purpose ?

Comment: actual found the ftp hung up...I implemented your changes and the images do not change at all.

Comment: that might be better to use jQuery load function